# When are model methods called in django

Tags: python, django, methods, model

I am trying to understand how model methods work. 
Taking the following example: [source here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    def baby_boomer_status(self):
        "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
        import datetime
        if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
            return "Pre-boomer"
        elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
            return "Baby boomer"
        else:
            return "Post-boomer"
```

When is `baby_boomer_status` method called?

I tried replacing `return` with `print` but the method was never called.

How does this work? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: They are called when you call them.

Comment: I recommend completing a tutorial on basic object-oriented programming in Python before trying to learn Django.

Comment: Wow, Remco and Bob. Nice helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a Person object

```
my_person = Person.objects.first()
```

You can call the model method:

```
my_person.baby_boomer_status()
```

Since this return a string, you can print its result

```
print my_person.baby_boomer_status()
```